# Custom-email-verification sample does not seem to work properly

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've set up our B2C tenant with the policies described here in attempt to get this sample to work: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/020f9e57a095e2c9d0ff1d644803b404a3f5511f/policies/custom-email-verifcation/policy

However running the PasswordReset flow it
a) does not seem to be pulling the selfAsserted.html from the blob store as specified in the TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml file
b) allows me to reset my password but sends the reset email from msonlineservicesteam@microsoftonline.com and not attempting to query the custom API endpoint

I'm thinking I've missed something obvious....?

Comment: It’s because the content definition for the password reset page is not being overridden/configured. This is not really an ideal approach anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I will take down this sample.
It’s been superseded by this

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email-sendgrid

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-email-verifcation-displaycontrol

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jas.  We were aware of the SendGrid and MailJet solution but would rather not use those.  We'd like to use our own API to send the email, which is why we were pointed to the above.  The only way currently do this is with a 3rd party service like SendGrid or MailJet?

Comment: No, the sample uses our generic REST API interface, and as an example calls sendgrid. You can call whatever API you like.

Comment: Sorry I see the Sendgrid doc and the Mailjet doc but is there an explanation on setting up on using our own APIs?  Or you're saying I should I follow either the Sendgrid or Mailjet sample but substitute our API for "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send" ?

Comment: Follow the doc and substitute the sendgrid endpoint for your own. It’s just a REST call the AAD B2C makes, and we provide a generic REST interface with the REST API technical profile.